# Please advise on database solution for the read-heavy service with almost no writes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I have a slowly growing collection of about 3 million tagged documents and I want to be able to select documents from this collection by tags as fast as reasonably (i.e. not writing custom indexing solution in c, etc) possible.

For example I want to select all documents tagged by "foo" and "bar" or select all documents tagged by "foo" and *not* "bar".

Another thing is a high(?) number of tags: 200k currently, 0.5-1kk planned and 2kk in worst case scenario. 
I know those numbers are not something out of ordinary by modern standards but personally I've never worked with datasets so big, my overall experience with databases is somehow limited and there are so many options available...

For now I'm considering mongodb because it has exactly what I need -- multikeys. Is mongobd good for fast querying?
Will other seemingly similar nosql projects (CouchDb, for example) better serve my purpose? Or should I try good old MySQL?

Should I look at "bigtable" projects like hypertable or hbase?

Comment: if you want *really* fast queries on relatively static data - cache everything, regardless of database.

Comment: By "2kk" you mean two million (2M) ?

Comment: @Thilo: I also use this notation sometimes :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, I will not be able to cache everything: I have a large amount of tags and amount of their combinations is just above the roof.

Comment: how many tags per document?  and how many documents per tag?  roughly.  those are important numbers...

Comment: Tags per document: from 10 to 1000-2000 with median of about 30-40 (yep, long tail distribution). It's harder to say how many documents per tag. Some tags are unique, some are very common, say 200-300k documents per tag may be even more. I'm thinking about discarding very common ones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB or Mysql would be fine if you have enough ram on the server.  Mongo is good for scaling horizontally with auto sharding.  Mongo will use more disk space than a MySQL.  For the fastest reads, it's always best to use redis or memcached for the most commonly used queries.

Comment: If almost any solution is good then which one is the simplest?